# $\|A_\delta f - f \|_p \to 0$ as $\delta \to 0$ for this function-to-function mapping $A_\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lp-spaces

For an $L^p$ function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and a positive number $\delta$, we define a new function $A_\delta f$ by the step function
$$  A_\delta f = \sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \textbf{avg }^\delta_n(f) \  \chi_{I^\delta_n} \ , $$
where $I^\delta_n$ is the interval $(\ (n-1)\delta,\, n\delta\ ]$ and $ \textbf{avg }^\delta_n(f)$ is the mean value
$$  \textbf{avg }^\delta_n (f) =  \frac 1 \delta \int_{I^\delta_n} f.  $$

**Question.** How to prove that
$$ \lim_{\delta \to 0} \| A_\delta f - f\|_p =0 \ ?$$
(The norm is of course the $L^p$-norm.)

**What I have / haven't done.** I already have proved that

\begin{align}
\text{the answer is YES if $f$ is of compact support. }
\end{align}
And what I have to do is to extend this result to the whole $L^p(\mathbb R)$ by the denseness of $C_c(\mathbb R)$ in $L^p(\mathbb R)$.

To do this I used the Minkowski inequality to get
$$  \|A_\delta f - f \|_p \le \|A_\delta (f - f_k)\|_p + \| A_\delta f_k -f_k \|_p + \|f-f_k\|_p \ , $$
where $f_k$ is a sequence in $C_c(\mathbb R)$ which converges to $f$ in $L^p(\mathbb R)$. Then the second and third terms in the right-hand side become small if $\delta$ is small and $k$ large.

But I don't see why the first term $\|A_\delta (f-f_k)\|_p$ becomes small when $\delta \to 0$ and $k \to \infty$. Is this true? If so, then how can I prove it?

Thanks for any help. The answer may or may not follow my approach.
You may even restrict $\delta$ to have the sequential values; that is, you may assume $\delta_n = 1/n$ or $\delta_n = 1/2^n$, etc, if that makes the thing easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The disjointness of $I_{n}^{\delta}$ yields that
\begin{align*}
\|A_{\delta}(f-f_{k})\|_{p}^{p}&=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|\text{avg}_{n}^{\delta}(f-f_{k})|^{p}|I_{n}^{\delta}|\\
&=\delta\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}|\text{avg}_{n}^{\delta}(f-f_{k})|^{p}.
\end{align*}
While,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left(\dfrac{1}{\delta}\int_{I_{n}^{\delta}}|f-f_{k}|\right)^{p}\leq\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\dfrac{1}{\delta}\int_{I_{n}^{\delta}}|f-f_{k}|^{p}=\dfrac{1}{\delta}\|f-f_{k}\|_{p}^{p},
\end{align*}
so $\|A_{\delta}(f-f_{k})\|_{p}^{p}\leq\|f-f_{k}\|_{p}^{p}$.

Comment: How do you get the first inequality?

Comment: There is a fact that, $\|f\|_{L^{r}(\mu)}\leq\|f\|_{L^{s}(\mu)}$ for $r\leq s$ and probability one measure $\mu$. Here $r=1$ and $s=p$.